# Retrieve data from linkedgeodata.org

Tags: sparql

I am trying to retrieve data from linkedgeodata.org/sparql

```
Prefix lgdo: <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/>
Select *
From <http://linkedgeodata.org>
{
    ?s a lgdo:Restaurant .
    ?s rdfs:label ?l .
    ?s geo:geometry ?g .
    Filter(bif:st_intersects (?g, bif:st_point (48.143889, 17.109722), 5.1)) .
}
```

But response is empty. I want to retrieve restaurants in Bratislava....5km from coordinates.

I used similar sparql code like in the example, I changed only class to restaurant and coordinates of the city, so I dont know where I am doing mistake.(http://linkedgeodata.org/OnlineAccess/SparqlEndpoints?v=bpg)

```
Prefix lgdo: <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/>
Select *
From <http://linkedgeodata.org>
{
    ?s a lgdo:Amenity .
    ?s rdfs:label ?l .
    ?s geo:geometry ?g .
    Filter(bif:st_intersects (?g, bif:st_point (12.372966, 51.310228), 0.1)) .
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see all types of things that fall within those coordinates by running the following query:

```
Prefix lgdo: <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/>
Select ?type, count(?s)
From <http://linkedgeodata.org>
{
    ?s a ?type .
    ?s rdfs:label ?l .
    ?s geo:geometry ?g .
Filter(bif:st_intersects (?g, bif:st_point (48.143889, 17.109722), 5.1)) .
} GROUP BY ?type
```

This query, using `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`, gives you counts for all different `types`. As you can see there are no restaurants falling in geographical area. Your query is not wrong, the database does not contain any restaurants for the given coordinates.